# Build Custom Journey Builder Template

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I know you can create custom journey activity in journey builder and you could also create a journey using marketing cloud out of box templates.

So I was wondering if you could create your own template in journey builder.

If there is a way, could you also provide documentations or examples?

Many thanks

Comment: I can see in the APIs there are endpoints for template creation and they work, they just don't display so I would assume this something coming in a future release

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not yet available in Marketing Cloud. 
I would recommand creating a sub folder in Journey Builder called "Templates" with pre-configured Journeys that you can copy and paste for re-use purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create Journey Builder templates as far as I know. Yet, you can copy the previous Journeys to use them again.